# How do I re-stream a filtered video stream using VLC?

Tags: command-line, vlc, cvlc

I have an input RTSP stream that I want to apply the "cartoon" gradient filter to before streaming on http. I've managed to stream and apply the filter to the local playback, but the http stream does not have the filtering applied.

```
cvlc -vvv input_stream rtsp://10.217.12.20:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264 --video-filter "gradient{type=1}" --sout '#duplicate{dst=http{vfilter=gradient{type=1},mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/coffeecam},dst=display}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work:

```
cvlc -vvv --daemon --pidfile ./coffee_stream.pid rtsp://10.217.112.30:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264 --sout="#transcode{vfilter=gradient{type=1},vcodec=theo,acodec=vorb,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http{mime=video/ogg},mux=ogg,dst=:8091}"
```